# Type DefaultTheme is not assignable to type DefaultTheme | ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, styled-components

I have created a npm package where I have extended *styled-components* **DefaultTheme**. When I am passing the theme which is a type of **DefaultTheme** it is gives some error saying `Type 'DefaultTheme' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme | ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)'.`
I am using styled-componets version `^5.2.0` & @types/styled-componets of version `^5.1.9`

Here is the error

```
(property) theme: DefaultTheme | ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)
Type 'DefaultTheme' is not assignable to type 'DefaultTheme | ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)'.ts(2322)
index.d.ts(350, 5): The expected type comes from property 'theme' which is declared here on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<ThemeProviderProps<DefaultTheme, DefaultTheme>, any, any>> & Readonly<...> & Readonly<...>'
```

Answer (score 0):

TypeScript expects a narrower type at this place.
Your passed type is `DefaultTheme | ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)`.
But according to the error message, `DefaultTheme OR ((theme: DefaultTheme) => DefaultTheme)` is expected.
To fix this, you need to add an extra check to translate a broad type to a narrower type.

To do this, you can use [type guards](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html).

```
const isDefaultTheme = (unknownValue): unknownValue is DefaultTheme => {
  // check unknownValue is DefaultTheme or not
  // return boolean
}

if (isDefaultTheme(someValue)) {
  // now type of someValue is DefaultTheme
}
```